# How to resolve npm error 'fetch_error' in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have tried to inject angular dependency more and more time by applying this command but every time gets this attached error. If you have any solution please share. Thank you

npm cache clean --force

npm install

npm install --legacy-peer-deps

[image]

Angular, npm, node version like this...
[image]

Comment: What does `npm cache verify` say?

Comment: yeah but still same error @MichaelD

Comment: Can you share the package.json file code snipped ?

Comment: @AbhishekPriyadarshi I have got my solution by bellowing command 1. npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org 2. npm install or npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Good @Md.ShafiqulIslam

Answer (score 2):

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: I have got my solution by bellowing command 
1. npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
2. npm install or npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: @Md.ShafiqulIslam I think it is better to post your solution as an answer. In case anyone can see quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try to look up the registry, I change the registry as https://www.npmjs.com by mistake, change it as follow

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org
2. npm install or npm install --legacy-peer-deps